Flutter Gradle Plugin migration causes error: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
I recently updated my flutter sdk to version 3.19. Upon doing that, this error started showing up whenever I run my flutter app.
enter image description here
I then followed the link to migrate the gradle plugins. Now i'm stuck with this error.
enter image description here
I already went through different stack overflow posts with similar issues but not the exact same. Tried their solutions but none of them worked.

Please post your errors and code as code-formatted text so others can easily follow and find them in search results.

Did you manage to solve this?

Instead of applying the plugins the old way, which is something like this (in Groovy):
apply from: 'com.android.application'

Do it the new way in the plugins block:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

See Gradle documentation on the difference.

In android/settings.gradle, change "com.android.application" version to 8.6.0 and kotlin version to 1.7.10
plugins {
 id "com.android.application" version "8.6.0" apply false
 id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

Next, go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl to:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip

Finaly, go to android/gradle.properties and delete:
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
You may get an error related to Namespace not specified when you run your project again.
Resolve it by adding namespace "com.example.myapp" inside android{} in android/app/build.gradle.
Replace "com.example.myapp" with your app id which can be found in defaultConfig{} inside the same file: android/app/build.gradle
